# Sharepoint and WCF interactions

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I try to read and create XML files on a Sharepoint 2010.
I know that Sharepoint exposed some services used to interract with the application (like /_vti_bin/ListData.svc or /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx or /_vti_bin/Webs.asmx) but i dont know how to use them and if they can do what i want to do.

If someone has a sample to help me or a link with a comprehensive documentation, thank you to please share with us.

Thank you in advance, have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i'm able to do what i wanted.

Here is the solution to read XML files on SharePoint 2010 with a WCF Service :

```
public string GetLocalisationCollection()
    {
        CopySoapClient client = new CopySoapClient();
        FieldInformation myFieldInfo = new FieldInformation();
        FieldInformation[] myFieldInfoArray = { myFieldInfo };
        byte[] myByteArray;
        client.GetItem(Configuration.LocalisationUri, out myFieldInfoArray, out myByteArray);

        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myByteArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference with examples: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979690(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa979690%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Have you tried to search on your own?

What particular problem do you have?

Comment: I search on my own with google and msdn documentation, but I must admit I was a little lost, since this is the first time I use SharePoint. Thx for the link